# How can I hide this setting-box on a click on the gear icon and anywhere outside of the body?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, settings

> > this the CSS I use.

```
.setting-box 
{
position: fixed;
left:-200px;
top:0;
width: 200px;
z-index: 1000;
min-height: 100vh; 
}
.toggle-setting 
{
position: absolute;
right: -34px;
top: 6em;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer; 
}
```

> I tried a lot of things but it doesn't work!
>
> > that code works very well but.
> >
> > > except when I click on the page the setting box doesn't close

```
$('.setting-box .toggle-setting').on('click',function () {
$(this).parent('.setting-box').toggleClass('open');

if ($(this).parent('.setting-box').hasClass('open')) {
$(this).parent('.setting-box').animate({
        left:0,
        },1000);

     } else {
       $(this, 'body').parent('.setting-box').animate({
            left:'-200'
      },1000);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first function do toggle setting box;

```
$('#gear-button').click(function() {
  $(".setting-box").toggleClass("display-block");
});
```

second function hide setting box on document click (body click)

```
// hide setting box on body click
$(document).on('click', function() {
  $(".setting-box").removeClass("display-block");
});
```

the third function stop the click event when the user clicks on a button or setting box to prevent document click

```
$("#gear-button, .setting-box").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

In general, you can use this template to add your own animation and classes.

the full example :

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asafari72/kgf8va9w/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

### EDIT

```
var clicked = false;

$('.setting-box .toggle-setting').on('click',function () {

if (clicked == false) {
$(this).parent('.setting-box').animate({
        'left' : '0',
        },1000);
  clicked = true;
     } else {
$(this).parent('.setting-box').animate({
        'left' : '-200px',
        },1000);
  clicked = false;
 }
console.log(clicked);
});

$(document).click( function () {
 var target = $(event.target);
 if (!target.is(".toggle-setting") && !target.is('.setting-box') && clicked == true) {
  $('.setting-box').animate({
     'left' :'-200px',
  },1000);
   clicked = false;
   console.log(clicked);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the settings block in another block, place the settings in the `align:center;`,
add from this from the `z-index:;` and make when you click on the gear, or anywhere, so that this block takes the style of `display:none;`. This may help you.